# What's the better way to reduce the impact to the familiar users when process redesigning or take place

Tags: web-app, e-commerce, checkout, redesign, optimisation

I have this e-commerce app [wishque.com](http://www.wishque.com) and I have added more features to checkout process lately. Now, I feel like the process has some odd spots. **I'm thinking of redesigning the checkout process.**

But, there are more familiar users. How can I **minimise the impact on the familiar users in a redesigning** the process.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true people hate change. It could scare them off. But there are ways of minimizing any recoil or you could even turn it to your advantage.

**Make small iterations**
A nice example is the case of Google and Yahoo. Google has changed it's logo multiple times over the years. They removed bevels and went from a serif to a sans serif font. Many people didn't notice or at least didn't dislike the changes.
Yahoo on the other hand changed their logo and got a sh*tstorm of critique over them.
The lesson here is to make small changes and implement them step by step.

**Actively include customers into the process**
You can turn your customer into advocates for your products by actively including them. Announce what you want to do. Ask for their opinion. Make them feel validated. Keep communicating.

[I believe this article to be very insightfull into the matter](https://medium.com/ux-immersion-interactions/designing-embraceable-change-a1ef057fe177#.9j20lmkgq)

Answer (score 1):

You're making a big assumption here: "Redesigning my checkout process will confuse people who are familiar with it".

**Are people familiar with your checkout process?**

So familiar that they'd be lost if it changed? It's hard for me to imagine someone getting used to a checkout process for most websites.

Unless you're running Amazon, I wouldn't be surprised if people forget the steps of your checkout process 5 minutes after they use it. But I'm also making an assumption, of course, and I'd have to find some way to test it.

**Will existing users be confused by the new process?**

A redesign will put your existing users in the same position as anyone who comes to the website for the first time.

I assume you're not planning to make the new checkout process confusing for new users, so why should it be confusing to existing users?

Unless they're closing their eyes and clicking on things from memory alone, it might not have as much impact as you're worried it will have.